# Integral group cohomology of Lie groups pure torsion in odd degree?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a compact finite-dimensional Lie group. Is it true that the integral cohomology $H^k(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ (where $BG$ is the classifying space of $G$) is pure torsion (i.e. finite) whenever $k$ is odd?

Comment: Certainly if $G$ is connected.  I'm not sure what happens when $G$ is disconnected.  The proof I'm thinking of is using the Serre spectral sequence (with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients) associated to $G\rightarrow EG\rightarrow BG$.  This works great if $G$ is connected, because then $BG$ is simply connected.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks! I think showing it in the connected case is sufficient, because in general one can invoke the Serre spectral sequence for the fibration $BG_0 \to BG \to B(G/G_0)$, where $G_0$ is the connected component of the identity. Compactness implies there are finitely many connected components, so $G/G_0$ is finite, and then we just need to use the fact that $H^p(BH, M)$ is finite for a finite group $H$ whenever $p > 0$ (it is annihilated by the order of $H$).

Comment: @JasonDeVito However, I was not able to follow your proposed argument, perhaps you would like to turn it into an answer?

Comment: I'm still unsure about the use of the spectral sequence for the fibration you just listed, because $B(G/G_0)$ need not be simply connected.  As far as my proposed argument - it's a lot harder than I was thinking.  So, I'll write a simpler argument below.

Comment: All the proofs I keep thinking of require non-trivial tricks.  So, here's a link the essentially the same question on mathoverflow:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61784/cohomology-of-bg-g-compact-lie-group

Comment: @JasonDeVito Forgive my naivete, but I actually cannot see why $H^k(BG,\mathbb{R}) = 0$ directly implies $H^k(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ is finite?

Comment: I'm sure it is complete overkill, but since G is a connected, compact CW complex its homotopy groups are all finitely generated.Since BG is a delooping its homotopy groups are also all finitely generated. This implies all its homology groups are finitely generated which means that if any of them are infinite they have a $\mathbb{Z}$ direct summand. So if you hom into $\mathbb{R}$ you would get a nontrivial group.

Comment: Meaning the cohomology is all coming from Ext groups of the previous homology which must be finite.

Comment: @Connor:  In general, a compact CW complex can have infinitely generated higher homotopy groups.  The usual example if $S^1 \vee S^2$.  Or, if you want a closed manifold example, there is $(S^1\times S^3)\sharp \mathbb{C}P^2$.   But it's easy to fix in this case:  a finite cover of $G$ is isomorphic to $T^k \times G_0$ with $T^k$ is a torus and $G_0$ is a simply connected compact Lie group.  Since higher homotopy groups are finitely generated for simply connected compact CW complex, and the higher homotopy groups of $T^k$ vanish, your argument applies.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that since it is connected it’s classifying space is simply connected and we can apply that as you said.

Answer (score 2):

The spectral sequence comment outlined in the comments is sufficient.

When $G$ is connected, use the Hopf theorem that $H^*(G;\Bbb Q) \cong \Lambda(x_{k_i})$, the exterior algebra on some number of generators $x_{k_i}$ with **odd** degree. Then the cohomological Serre spectral sequence applied to $BG \to EG \to G$ forces $BG$ to be a polynomial algebra on generators of degree $|x_{k_i}| + 1$. (The proof is not trivial but not altogether difficult.) A more complicated approach follows from Chern-Weyl theory. In any case the generators of this polynomial algebra lie in even degree, so $H^*(BG;\Bbb Q)$ is concentrated in even degree.

When $G$ is not connected, the Serre spectral sequence for $BG_0 \to BG \to B(G/G_0)$ takes the form of $$H^*(G/G_0; H^*(BG_0)) \implies H^*(BG),$$ where the $E_2$ page is *group cohomology* for the action of $G/G_0$ on $H^*(BG_0)$ (induced by conjugation on $G_0$).

If you work over the rationals, because $G/G_0$ is finite we have that $$H^*(G/G_0; H^*(BG_0)) = H^0(G/G_0; H^*(BG_0)) = (H^*(BG_0))^{G/G_0}.$$ This is again a graded vector space, which is concentrated in even degrees because $H^*(BG_0;\Bbb Q)$ is. So $H^*(BG;\Bbb Q)$ is concentrated in even degrees for all compact Lie groups $G$, which is what you wanted.